# How to change alignment of bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a bar plot of length class on the x axis against frequency. Lengths are rounded down, so I'd like the bar for 0cm to plot to the right of 0, rather than centred on 0.

Consider the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(x=seq(0,50,5), y=runif(11))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_col()
```

which produces

[image: Current behaviour]

I'd like it to be similar to

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x+mean(diff(x)/2), y=y)) + geom_col()
```

[image: Ideal behaviour]

Is there a way to do this by changing the `position` argument for `geom_col` rather than manipulating the data directly?

Comment: try `position_nudge(x = 2.25)`. But you have to find out the needed value by trying out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the newest version of [`ggplot 3.4.0`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases/tag/v3.4.0) you can use the argument `just` in `geom_col` or `geom_bar`:

> Adjustment for column placement. Set to 0.5 by default, meaning that
> columns will be centered about axis breaks. Set to 0 or 1 to place
> columns to the left/right of axis breaks. Note that this argument may
> have unintended behaviour when used with alternative positions, e.g.
> position_dodge().

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(x=seq(0,50,5), y=runif(11))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_col(just = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How to align the line from `geom_errobar` ? `just` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

A workaround that should work even if the data changes:

library(ggplot2)

```
d <- data.frame(x= seq(0,50,round(runif(1)*10)))
d$y = runif(nrow(d))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_col(width = min(diff(sort(d$x)))*0.9, 
            position = position_nudge(x = min(diff(sort(d$x)))*0.9/2))
```

**Original answer**
Hope this helps:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(x=seq(0,50,5), y=runif(11))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_col(position = position_nudge(x = 2))
```

Comment: That definitely improves it, but it still need me to calculate the nudge amount as Roman said.

Comment: True. You can set the width to get a "perfect" nudge:
     geom_col(width = 4, position = position_nudge(x = 2))

However, this is still not perfect since you have to calculate a nice width...