# Adjusting alignment of bars to x-axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I wrote the code below which works without errors but the two bars are not aligned with x-axis labels "pre" and "post." I have tried incorporating the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048743/how-to-change-alignment-of-bars-in-ggplot) but it does not seem to fix the misalignment issue in my case.

```
dput(df[1:2, c(1,2,3,4)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(treatment = c(0, 1), total_posts = c(2055L, 
866L), count = c(77L, 22L), collective_share = c(3.74695863746959, 
2.54041570438799)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

graph code:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = treatment, fill=treatment,  y = share)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    ylab("% Share of mentions") + 
    theme(text=element_text(size=10)) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("pre", "post"))+
  labs(fill='implementation')+ 
      xlab("Period")  +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

Comment: Or `aes(x = factor(treatment_implementation, labels = c("pre", "post")), ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `scale_x_discrete`, then your `x` value should be a factor, not numeric. And then you just need to set the `labels=`, not the `limits=`

```
ggplot(data = collective_action_mentions, aes(x = factor(treatment_implementation), fill=treatment_implementation,  y = collective_share)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
  ylab("% Share of collective action mentions") + 
  theme(text=element_text(size=10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("pre","post"))+
  labs(fill='Policy implementation')+ 
  xlab("Period")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"))
```

[image]